# Is there a way to integrate Nifi Server with AWS Cognito?

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, apache-nifi

I am using AWS Cognito in our organization for authentication and would like to deploy Apache Nifi to our users.

Nifi.properties file has Open ID SSO settings but would like to know how to populate these accurately for indegrating a Cognito Pool.

```
# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
```

I would want to users to be redirected to Cognito login page and post authenticating be redirected to the Nifi Server.

Comment: oidc stands for _openid connect_. search for documentation how to configure openid client for cognito. for example - check this [article](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/openid-connect-authorization-code-flow-with-aws-cognito-246997abd11a).

Comment: Thanks @daggett .. This helps... I will try this with my Nifi Server and update. Since Cognito is not a full Open ID Provider, I was a little skeptical and was wondering if someone has actually used Nifi with COgnito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache Ranger for this like is explained [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60001/hdf-20-integrating-secured-nifi-with-secured-range.html) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/implementing-authorization-and-auditing-using-apache-ranger-on-amazon-emr/).